# Basic Calculus question - square numbers

Tags: calculus, square-numbers

I am new to calculus. I am stuck with this:

if

$x-\frac{5}{\sqrt{x}} = 26$

$x - 5\sqrt{x} = $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first equation, for $\sqrt{x}=t$ we have:
$$
t^3-26t-5=0 \iff (t+5)(t^2-5t-1)=0
$$

since $t=-5 \rightarrow \sqrt{x}=-5$ is not possible, we have only
$$
t^2-5t-1=0 \iff x-5\sqrt{x}=1
$$